# SVG <animate> Works in Safari, Not Chrome

Tags: html, animation, svg, smil

My understanding is that SMIL animations are supported by chrome; however my svg SMIL animation **does not** in Chrome (v107) while it **does** work in Safari (v16.0)

Here's a [link](https://codepen.io/nickbewley/pen/zYjpgNR) to a codepen illustrating the issue. Why won't this `<animation>` work across browsers?

```
<svg width="46" height="62" viewBox="0 0 46 62" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M 23 40 C 26.376 40 28.889 41.717 29.586 42.414 C 31.827 44.655 33 46.675 33 50 C 33 51.479 32.678 52.894 32.096 54.17 C 31.523 55.427 30.696 56.55 29.676 57.467 C 27.932 59.032 25.618 60 22.999 60 C 20.386 60 18.076 59.036 16.334 57.477 C 15.309 56.558 14.479 55.432 13.904 54.17 C 13.322 52.894 13 51.479 13 50 C 13 46.675 14.173 44.655 16.414 42.414 C 17.111 41.717 19.624 40 23 40 Z" id="shape" fill="#007AFF" stroke="white" stroke-width="4">
     <animate          
      attributename="d"
      begin="G.click"
      from="M 23 40 C 26.376 40 28.889 41.717 29.586 42.414 C 31.827 44.655 33 46.675 33 50 C 33 51.479 32.678 52.894 32.096 54.17 C 31.523 55.427 30.696 56.55 29.676 57.467 C 27.932 59.032 25.618 60 22.999 60 C 20.386 60 18.076 59.036 16.334 57.477 C 15.309 56.558 14.479 55.432 13.904 54.17 C 13.322 52.894 13 51.479 13 50 C 13 46.675 14.173 44.655 16.414 42.414 C 17.111 41.717 19.624 40 23 40 Z"
      to="M 23 2 C 29.018 2 34.385 4.034 38.179 7.421 C 41.794 10.647 44 15.131 44 20.365 C 44 22.74 43.043 26.026 41.334 29.89 C 39.649 33.7 37.33 37.861 34.818 41.916 C 30.621 48.692 25.957 55.057 22.998 58.816 C 20.041 55.06 15.379 48.7 11.182 41.928 C 8.671 37.873 6.351 33.712 4.666 29.901 C 2.958 26.036 2 22.746 2 20.365 C 2 15.119 4.203 10.637 7.812 7.416 C 11.606 4.029 16.976 2 23 2 Z" 
      dur=".4s" 
    />
  </path>
</svg>
```

Comment: SVG is case sensitive if standalone so you'd need attributeName if that's the case. Also dur values are not allowed to start with a period/full stop so you'd need dur="0.4s"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They apparently don't handle *event-value* on elements outside of the SVG namespace. This should be considered a bug and I opened [BUG 1395274](https://crbug.com/1395274).

As for a workaround, the obvious one is to use JS instead:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  document.querySelector("path animate").beginElement();
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}

svg {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<svg width="146" height="62" viewBox="0 0 146 62" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M 23 40 C 26.376 40 28.889 41.717 29.586 42.414 C 31.827 44.655 33 46.675 33 50 C 33 51.479 32.678 52.894 32.096 54.17 C 31.523 55.427 30.696 56.55 29.676 57.467 C 27.932 59.032 25.618 60 22.999 60 C 20.386 60 18.076 59.036 16.334 57.477 C 15.309 56.558 14.479 55.432 13.904 54.17 C 13.322 52.894 13 51.479 13 50 C 13 46.675 14.173 44.655 16.414 42.414 C 17.111 41.717 19.624 40 23 40 Z" id="shape" fill="#007AFF" stroke="white" stroke-width="4">
     <animate          
      attributename="d"
      begin="indefinite"
      from="M 23 40 C 26.376 40 28.889 41.717 29.586 42.414 C 31.827 44.655 33 46.675 33 50 C 33 51.479 32.678 52.894 32.096 54.17 C 31.523 55.427 30.696 56.55 29.676 57.467 C 27.932 59.032 25.618 60 22.999 60 C 20.386 60 18.076 59.036 16.334 57.477 C 15.309 56.558 14.479 55.432 13.904 54.17 C 13.322 52.894 13 51.479 13 50 C 13 46.675 14.173 44.655 16.414 42.414 C 17.111 41.717 19.624 40 23 40 Z"
      to="M 23 2 C 29.018 2 34.385 4.034 38.179 7.421 C 41.794 10.647 44 15.131 44 20.365 C 44 22.74 43.043 26.026 41.334 29.89 C 39.649 33.7 37.33 37.861 34.818 41.916 C 30.621 48.692 25.957 55.057 22.998 58.816 C 20.041 55.06 15.379 48.7 11.182 41.928 C 8.671 37.873 6.351 33.712 4.666 29.901 C 2.958 26.036 2 22.746 2 20.365 C 2 15.119 4.203 10.637 7.812 7.416 C 11.606 4.029 16.976 2 23 2 Z" 
      dur="0.4s" 
    />
  </path>
</svg>
<button>
  start animation
</button>
```

Or if you really don't want to use JS, then you can hack something around by inserting an `<svg>` element in your button... but probably don't do that.

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}

svg {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<svg width="146" height="62" viewBox="0 0 146 62" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M 23 40 C 26.376 40 28.889 41.717 29.586 42.414 C 31.827 44.655 33 46.675 33 50 C 33 51.479 32.678 52.894 32.096 54.17 C 31.523 55.427 30.696 56.55 29.676 57.467 C 27.932 59.032 25.618 60 22.999 60 C 20.386 60 18.076 59.036 16.334 57.477 C 15.309 56.558 14.479 55.432 13.904 54.17 C 13.322 52.894 13 51.479 13 50 C 13 46.675 14.173 44.655 16.414 42.414 C 17.111 41.717 19.624 40 23 40 Z" id="shape" fill="#007AFF" stroke="white" stroke-width="4">
     <animate          
      attributename="d"
      begin="G.click"
      from="M 23 40 C 26.376 40 28.889 41.717 29.586 42.414 C 31.827 44.655 33 46.675 33 50 C 33 51.479 32.678 52.894 32.096 54.17 C 31.523 55.427 30.696 56.55 29.676 57.467 C 27.932 59.032 25.618 60 22.999 60 C 20.386 60 18.076 59.036 16.334 57.477 C 15.309 56.558 14.479 55.432 13.904 54.17 C 13.322 52.894 13 51.479 13 50 C 13 46.675 14.173 44.655 16.414 42.414 C 17.111 41.717 19.624 40 23 40 Z"
      to="M 23 2 C 29.018 2 34.385 4.034 38.179 7.421 C 41.794 10.647 44 15.131 44 20.365 C 44 22.74 43.043 26.026 41.334 29.89 C 39.649 33.7 37.33 37.861 34.818 41.916 C 30.621 48.692 25.957 55.057 22.998 58.816 C 20.041 55.06 15.379 48.7 11.182 41.928 C 8.671 37.873 6.351 33.712 4.666 29.901 C 2.958 26.036 2 22.746 2 20.365 C 2 15.119 4.203 10.637 7.812 7.416 C 11.606 4.029 16.976 2 23 2 Z" 
      dur="0.4s" 
    />
  </path>
</svg>
<!-- really just to show how Chrome's bug behave don't do that... -->
<button style="position: relative">
  <svg id=G style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; left:0; top:0;"></svg>
  start animation
</button>
```

*Ps: Note that as mentioned by Robert in the comments, you need to set the initial `0` in the `dur` attribute for Firefox to accept it.*

---

The Bug has been fixed in latest Canary *110.0.5460.0*.

Answer (score 0):

Another style work-around,
that gets you **tight coupling** between your SVG and JS code capturing the click,
is a native JavaScript Web Component, supported in all modern browsers.

```css
body {
  background-color: green;
}

svg {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<svg-marker color="gold"></svg-marker>

<script>
customElements.define("svg-marker", class extends HTMLElement{
  connectedCallback(){
    this.innerHTML = `
        <svg width="146" height="62" viewBox="0 0 146 62" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M 23 40 C 26.376 40 28.889 41.717 29.586 42.414 C 31.827 44.655 33 46.675 33 50 C 33 51.479 32.678 52.894 32.096 54.17 C 31.523 55.427 30.696 56.55 29.676 57.467 C 27.932 59.032 25.618 60 22.999 60 C 20.386 60 18.076 59.036 16.334 57.477 C 15.309 56.558 14.479 55.432 13.904 54.17 C 13.322 52.894 13 51.479 13 50 C 13 46.675 14.173 44.655 16.414 42.414 C 17.111 41.717 19.624 40 23 40 Z" 
                fill="${this.getAttribute("color") || "#007AFF"}" stroke="white" stroke-width="4">
            <animate begin="freeze" fill="freeze" attributename="d" dur="0.4s" 
                     from="M 23 40 C 26.376 40 28.889 41.717 29.586 42.414 C 31.827 44.655 33 46.675 33 50 C 33 51.479 32.678 52.894 32.096 54.17 C 31.523 55.427 30.696 56.55 29.676 57.467 C 27.932 59.032 25.618 60 22.999 60 C 20.386 60 18.076 59.036 16.334 57.477 C 15.309 56.558 14.479 55.432 13.904 54.17 C 13.322 52.894 13 51.479 13 50 C 13 46.675 14.173 44.655 16.414 42.414 C 17.111 41.717 19.624 40 23 40 Z"
                     to="M 23 2 C 29.018 2 34.385 4.034 38.179 7.421 C 41.794 10.647 44 15.131 44 20.365 C 44 22.74 43.043 26.026 41.334 29.89 C 39.649 33.7 37.33 37.861 34.818 41.916 C 30.621 48.692 25.957 55.057 22.998 58.816 C 20.041 55.06 15.379 48.7 11.182 41.928 C 8.671 37.873 6.351 33.712 4.666 29.901 C 2.958 26.036 2 22.746 2 20.365 C 2 15.119 4.203 10.637 7.812 7.416 C 11.606 4.029 16.976 2 23 2 Z"/>
          </path>
        </svg>`;
    this.onclick = (evt) => {
      this.querySelector("animate").beginElement();
    }
  }
});

</script>
```